# Django - Showing different templates to admins

Tags: django, django-permissions

In Django what's the best way to implement templates with extra functionality for users with 'admin' permissions.

I'm not sure if I should create a set of completely different views specific for admins or integrate it into my existing views and templates like 'if user is an admin' everywhere.

Is there a standard way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 10):

This will show the stuff only if you are active and staff not admin:

```
{% if request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff %}
    {% include "foo/bar.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

If you wanna show only and ONLY for admin you have to do that:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    ADD your admin stuff there.
{% endif %}
```

Differences about these fields [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff).

Answer (score 3):

If you have the the user available in template context you can do:

```
{% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
    Only the admin will see this code. For example include some admin template here:
   {% include "foo/bar.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

User will be available in your template f you use `RequestContext` and your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting contains `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`, which is default. See [authentication data in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates) as reference.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an advocate of keeping as much logic out of the view layer (speaking generally about the MVC Design Pattern). So why not use decorators to direct your user to different views based upon their privilege? In your urls.py, define a pattern for admins:

```
url(r'^admin/$', 'user.views.admin_index'),
#do so for your other admin views, maybe more elegantly than this quick example
```

Then define a decorator to kick the user out if they're not an admin

```
def redirect_if_not_admin(fn):
def wrapper(request):
    if request.user.is_staff():
        return fn(request)
    #or user.is_superuser(), etc
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Permission_Denied/')
return wrapper
```

And in your admin views

```
@redirect_if_not_admin
def index(request):
##do your thing
```

It's more code than the other two answers, which are not wrong. It's just a personal preference to keep clutter down in the views.